# How to give a function as a parameter to a constructor taking an Object in VB.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, syntax

I have a class in C# that i need to reimplement in VB. Only the constructor is relevant here, it looks like this:

```
public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, DefaultCanExecute) { }
public ActionCommand(Action<object> exec, Predicate<object> canExec)
{
    //stuff...
}
```

This version works. Well, my VB.NET version does not. It looks like this:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal execute As Object)
    Me.New(execute, AddressOf DefaultCanExecute)
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal execute As Action(Of Object), ByVal canExec As Predicate(Of Object))
    'stuff...
End Sub
```

DefaultCanExecute is a private boolean function with no params always returning true.

When I try this in C#, it works:

```
var Foo = new ActionCommand(Bar);
```

In VB, the following fails:

```
Dim Foo As VariantType = New RelayCommand(Bar)
```

The Sub in VB looks like that:

```
Private Sub Bar(ByVal obj As Object)
    'stuff...
End Sub
```

And the C# version for the sake of completeness:

```
private void Bar(object obj)
{
    //stuff...
}
```

Does someone have an idea why the VB version does not work? Thank you :)

Comment: You might want to exand on "fails": Compile error? Runtime Exception? Unexpected result?

Comment: Why not `execute As Action(Of Object)` instead of `execute As Object`?

Comment: @crashmstr I get a compilation error stating that the parameter obj is missing. But I want to give the function as a parameter, not call it.

Comment: @juharr That would not be a difference. I tried that, but it did not solve my problem. The C# version works with object though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me in the VB.NET

```vb
Public Sub New(ByVal execute As Action(Of Object))
    MyClass.New(execute, AddressOf DefaultCanExecute)
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal execute As Action(Of Object), 
               ByVal canExec As Predicate(Of Object))
    'stuff...
End Sub
```

Then using like this:

```vb
Private Sub Bar(ByVal obj As Object)
    'stuff...
End Sub

Dim Foo As New RelayCommand(AddressOf Bar)
```

If you want pass function(pointer to function) as parameter use `AddressOf` keyword

Answer (score 0):

VariantType is an Enum and you cannot cast your RelayCommand class to an Enum.

To make the VB version equivalent to the C# change

`Dim Foo As VariantType = New RelayCommand(Bar)`

to

`Dim Foo = New RelayCommand(Bar)`

Comment: Oh sorry, that was another syntax mistake of mine :D strange that the compiler didnt tell me. Well, I changed the code and I'm afraid that the problem persists. :/